# Making contingency table from from values given by table function

Tags: r, contingency

I have a vector like this :

```
> agg$RNAtype
 [1] "HnRn" "HyRy" "HnRn" "HyRn" "HnRn" "HnRn" "HnRn" "HnRn" "HnRy" "HnRn" "HnRy"
[12] "HnRn"
```

Now when I use table function, it gives the following:

```
> table(agg$RNAtype)

HnRn HnRy HyRn HyRy 
   8    2    1    1
```

But I want to make a 2x2 contingency table (in the form of a matrix), where the first row will have values of HnRn and HyRn. And the second row will have values of HnRy and HyRy. How can I do it?

I am ultimately planning to do fisher's exact test and chisquare test.

Comment: See e.g. first example in `?fisher.test` and second example in `?chisq.test` on how to arrange counts in a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vec <- scan(what="")
1: "HnRn" "HyRy" "HnRn" "HyRn" "HnRn" "HnRn" "HnRn" "HnRn" "HnRy" "HnRn" "HnRy"
12:  "HnRn"
13: 
Read 12 items
```

Looks like you want to cross-classify on the 2nd and fourth characters in each item:

```
> table(substr(vec,4,4), substr(vec,2,2))

    n y
  n 8 1
  y 2 1
```

That's a bit crytic so use the labeling feature of table to improve the annotation:

```
> tbl <- table(`4th`=substr(vec,4,4), `2nd`=substr(vec,2,2))
> tbl
   2nd
4th n y
  n 8 1
  y 2 1
```

Table-objects are suitable input for `fisher.test`:

```
> fisher.test(tbl)

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  tbl
p-value = 0.4545
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
   0.03405901 351.00812616
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  3.463796
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @BondedDust's answer is better, but if you just want to rearrange the table you have you could presumably do

```
matrix(table(agg$RNAtype),nrow=2)
```

(as @Henrik points out in comment above, this is very similar to examples in `?fisher.test` and `?chisq.test` ...)

By default R constructs matrices in "column-major" order, so this should get the order of entries the way you want it.